# Django Foreign key field validation in a forms or models ( getting info created by only that user from foreign key)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to build courses and add lessons to a course later and the problem I encounter is that every user can choose to add courses to another person created courses. 
Like if you create some courses, another user will see as an option to add his lesson to it

**views.py**

```
def creatingLessonsForm(request):
    form = CreatingLessonsForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.CreatedBy = request.user
        post.save()
        form = CreatingLessonsForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'courses/creatingLessonsForm.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class CreatingCourses(models.Model):
    NameOfTheCourses = models.CharField("Name of the courses", max_length=60, blank=False)
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CreatedBy = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name= "Select document for courses introduction",  blank=True , null=True)
    IncludeTest = models.ForeignKey(GenaratedTest, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name= "Include test for courses", blank=True , null=True)
    AdditionalInfo = models.TextField("Additional info for courses introduction", max_length=300, blank=False)
    Note = models.TextField("Notes", max_length=180, blank=True)
    Show_the_courses = models.BooleanField(verbose_name= "Show the courses for everyone?",default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.NameOfTheCourses) if self.NameOfTheCourses else ''

class CreatingLessons(models.Model):
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(CreatingCourses, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    NameOfTheLesson = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name= "Name of the lesson",  blank=False)
    Document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name= "Document for lesson",  blank=True , null=True)
    CreatedBy = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Lesson = models.TextField(max_length=250, verbose_name= "Lesson", blank=False)
    Note = models.TextField("Notes", max_length=100, blank=True)
    Show_the_lesson = models.BooleanField(verbose_name= "Show the lesson inside courses?",default=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CreatingCoursesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CreatingCourses
        fields = ['NameOfTheCourses', 'Category', 'IncludeTest', 'Document'  , 'AdditionalInfo', 'Note', 'Show_the_courses' ]   

class CreatingLessonsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CreatingLessons
        fields = ['Courses', 'NameOfTheLesson', 'Document', 'Lesson', 'Note', 'Show_the_lesson']
```

Image of webpage:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your issue? You only want users top be able to be able to see the courses they created?

Comment: yes I would like to make that user can only see courses in an option list of his created courses

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the user when you initialize the form and then filter the queryset for the available courses that can be selected

```
class CreatingLessonsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, data=None, user=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(data, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Courses'].queryset = CreatingCourses.objects.filter(CreatedBy=user)
```

And then when you initialize the form pass the user

```
# When rendering the initial form
form = CreatingLessonsForm(user=request.user)
# When passing POST data to the form
form = CreatingLessonsForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to modify your to filter the courses by user.

```
class CreatingLessonsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request_user = kwargs.pop('request_user')

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['Courses'].queryset = self.fields['Courses'].queryset.filter(
            CreatedBy=request_user)
```

For that to work you will need to pass in the user of the request to the form, maybe like this:

```
def creatingLessonsForm(request):
    data = request.POST.copy()
    data['request_user'] = request.user
    form = CreatingLessonsForm(data)
    ...
```